# How to speed up dictionary build in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have looked at the links but nothing appears to apply.  I am doing what I thought would be a simple build of three dictionaries that I use elsewhere.  They are not all that large but this function takes almost 4 minutes to complete.  I am likely missing something and as I would like this to run faster.  This is Python 3.4

```
class VivifiedDictionary(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        value = self[key] = type(self)()
        return value

def dict_build(exclude_chrY):
    coordinate_intersection_dict = VivifiedDictionary()
    aberration_list_dict = VivifiedDictionary()
    gene_list_dict = VivifiedDictionary()

    if eval(exclude_chrY):
        chr_y = ""
    else:
        chr_y = "chrY"
    abr_type_list = ["del", "ins"]
    mouse_list = ["chr1", "chr2", "chr3", "chr4", "chr5", "chr6", "chr7", "chr8", "chr9", "chr10", "chr11", "chr12", "chr13", "chr14", "chr15", "chr16", "chr17", "chr18", "chr19", "chrX", chr_y]

    for chrom in mouse_list:
        for aberration in abr_type_list:
            coordinate_intersection_dict[chrom][aberration] = []
            aberration_list_dict[chrom][aberration] = []
            gene_list_dict[chrom][aberration] = []
```

Comment: Your code runs in a fraction of a second on my machine. Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Same here -- I added a line to execute dict_build, and it still completes in under a second.

Comment: Well, this is embarrassing.  When I call it as above it does indeed run in a fraction of a second.  But when I call it deep in my code it does not.  I did not believe the position mattered.  I will need to explore this a bit more.

Comment: Are you sure you are not rebuilding it every time you look something up in it?  This can happen if you use some expression which involves this function in a filter or map.

Answer (score 0):

Pleas check this The [Python Profilers](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html)  I think this may help in finding the bottleneck in your bigger script.